# why my ng-model doesn't bind?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following html:

```
<form ng-submit="addPath()">
                <input type="text" ng-model="newPathText"  style="width: 500px;" placeholder="Enter a local or network folder location (e.g., K:\documents\new-york)">
                <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add" style="margin-bottom: 10px">
            </form>
```

and the js code behind:

```
 $scope.addPath = function() {
        $scope.watchedFolders.push($scope.newPathText);
        apiService.addScanPath($scope.newPathText)
        $scope.newPathText= '';
    };
```

however, when i debug it and the addPath() is being called, i see that '$scope.newPathText' is always coming empty ('')...am i missing anything here?

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me, you need to provide some more context + code?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or plunkr?.

Comment: isn't because you just assigned it with `$scope.newPathText= '';`????

Comment: Your code is correct. If it doesn't work, then it got be something else.

http://jsfiddle.net/mCu57/

Comment: @sza here's an example that breaks his code (I had to use Plunker because jsFliddle doesn't support extra files): http://plnkr.co/edit/T7OuxbJdbrhmWYpxVgkf?p=preview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't data bind your views to primitive types because of the prototypical nature of scopes. What's probably happening in your case is that your view is bound to a child scope which is different from the controller scope. Try changing your model to something like this:

```
$scope.newPath = { text: ''};
```

and then bind your view to it:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newPath.text" ... >
```

That will ensure your view is bound to the correct scope.

This issue with primitives can be avoided by following a simple guideline: always have a . (dot) in your ng-model attributes. This [post](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) has valuable information on that matter.

Comment: I think it would have worked if you used `this` instead of the `$scope` from closure, "this" being the scope the function is called from.